# Include header row while extracting the table as csv to s3 in data pipeline AWS service

Tags: header, amazon-data-pipeline

while extracting the entire table from RDS to s3 in csv format.
Header column is not included.
what option should we choose to include the Header row in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email'
UNION ALL
SELECT firstName, lastName, email
FROM users

Answer (score 0):

SELECT '1st_name', 'last_name' UNION ALL SELECT u.firstName as 1st_name, u.lastName FROM users u;

You just need to select 'alias' name as column name when you have alias. It works.